# Decimals as keys for unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++17

I've often heard that you're not supposed to use float values as keys in an unordered_map or hash tables. For my use case, I have float values that are guaranteed to only be up to the hundredths in decimal value. As these decimals come in, I would like to count the number of times they appear. I only need ~90% accuracy in counting. Would using a hash table to store counts be viable, or would this run into too many performance issues?

Comment: "_Would using a hash table to store counts be viable, or would this run into too many performance issues?_" Reason why you "_often heard that you're not supposed to use float values as keys in an unordered_map or hash tables._" is not performance, it's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: It's fine to use a `float` for map keys so long as you know what you're doing. And most folk, even experienced programmers, don't. In your case though, can't you multiply the inputs by 100, and truncate to an integral type?

Comment: whoa okay i didn't even think of the multiplying thing that's a genius idea thank you

Comment: A more generalized discussion of Bathsheba's suggestion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: Do I even have to truncate it to an integral type? Is there ever a case in which a.0 + b.0 != (a+b).0?

Comment: Why not multiply the float value by 100, coonvert to int and use that as a key (with uniform rounding as in `int key = int(floorf((value * 100.f) + .5f));`),. That way, the behaviour of your program is well defined and clear.  Floating point values are always approximations...  This brings in some level of uncertanty,  that's why it is not advisable to use them as keys to a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to create an histogram.  Using a map for a histogram is a waste of resources.

A simple array, or vector, is more than enough, will work fine to this task, and will always be more efficient than a map.

```
constexpr const float hist_bin_width = .01f; // change to wanted resolution.

// because of IEEE floating point limitations: 
//   max resolution is (hist_max - hist_min) / (1 << 24).
// which will give you 16 Mega bins (1 << 24) plus or minus 1. 
// but you shouldn't need that high of a resolution.

// So we can use multiplication in code below for performance
constexpr const float hist_inv_bin_width = 1.f / hist_bin_width;   

constexpr const float hist_min  = -1.f;       // lower limit
constexpr const float hist_max  =  1.f;       // upper limit

size_t samples_count = 0;     // total number of vallues tallied.
// used to count out-of-bounds values.
size_t below_min_count = 0;
size_t above_max_count = 0;

 // useful, note that some compilers may not vhave a constexpr floorf() 
inline constexpr int value_to_index(float value) noexcept
{
    return int(floorf(((value - hist_min) * hist_inv_bin_width) + .5f));
}

inline constexpr float index_to_value(int i) noexcept
{
    return (i * hist_bin_with) + hist_min; 
}

void Tally(std::vector<size_t>& histogram, float value) noexcept
{
    ++samples_count;

    int i = value_to_index(value);
    if (i < 0)
        ++below_min_count;
    else if (i >= histogram.size())
        ++above_max_count;
    else
        ++histogram[i];
}
// ..

int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> histogram;
    histogram.resize(1 + value_to_index(hist_max));
    
    std::vector<float> input_values;

    //...

    for (auto val : input_values)
        Tally(histogram, val);
   
    // ...
    
    return 0;
}
```

If you are worried about the size and range of you histogram, consider this: 32-bit floats have 24 data bits in the mantissa, they can represent only 1<<24 = 16777218 distinct values at a resolution of .01. Other values will either be smaller than .01, or so large that the gap between two consecutve binary values will be larger than .01.  This rule of thumb is precise enough for all resolutions.  Note: it is an approximation only because (1/.01 =) 100 is not an exact power of 2, but it still is quite precise.

Any histogram can only be that large before being mathematically useless at *any* resolution.  The hard limit of the size of a useful histogram of 32 bit values (using vector<uint32_t> instead of vector<size_t>) to around 64 MB, using size_t which is 64-bit, the largest mathematically useful histogram at *any* resolution would take around 128 MB of RAM.  That's not very much for modern computers, it's not even that large for a smart phone or a raspberry PI.

The maximum useful range for your input values, and thus the max useful range for your histogram would be the interval [-(1<<23)x10^-2, +(1<<23)x10^-2]

Comment: The problem is I don't know the ranges of my values. They come in at random

Comment: Every et of random values has a range.  Every sample set used in engineering has a useful range.  Even with a range of -10000 to +10000, your histogram would only be 16MB,  which is not that large for modern computers, in practical terms,: you could have a gigabyte-sized histogram and still  be OK. But, is such a large histogram useful for analysis?  Probably not.  If you are dealing with a very large range, then a histogram at .01 resolultion is a way overkill, and will not be useful for analysis, because of the limits imposed by the number of bits in the mantissa of floating point values.